# $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ is countable

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ is countable

---

**My attempt:**

*Lemma*: $A$ is countable if and only if there exists a injectve mapping from $A$ to $\Bbb N$.

We define a mapping $f:\Bbb N\times\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ by $f(k,l)= 2^k3^l$. Next we prove $f$ is injective.

Suppose that $(k_1,l_1)$ and $(k_2,l_2)\in\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ and that $f(k_1,l_1) = f(k_2,l_2)$. Then $2^{k_1}3^{l_1}=2^{k_2}3^{l_2}$.

If $k_1>k_2$, then $2^{k_1}$ is not divisible by $2^{k_2}$. Furthermore, $2^{k_1}$ is not divisible by $3^{l_2}$ since $2$ and $3$ are prime numbers. It follows that $2^{k_1}$ is not divisible by $2^{k_2}3^{l_2}=2^{k_1}3^{l_1}$. Thus $2^{k_1}$ is not divisible by $2^{k_1}3^{l_1}$, which is clearly a contradiction.

By assuming $k_1<k_2$, or $l_1<l_2$, or $l_1>l_2$, we can easily obtain similar contradictions. Thus $k_1=k_2$ and $l_1=l_2$. Hence $(k_1,l_1)$ = $(k_2,l_2)$.

As a result, $f$ is injective and hence $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ is countable.

---

> Does this proof look fine or contain gaps? Do you have suggestions? Many thanks for your dedicated help!

---

**Update:** On the basis of @spaceisdarkgreen's commnet, I should explicitly mention that $f$ is injective by The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.

Comment: In the third paragraph it should be If $k_1 >k_2$, then $2^{k_1}$ “is” divisible by $2^{k_2}$. Now you need to fix the remaining argument as well.

Comment: Do you suspect your proof has any gaps? It is injective by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: @AnuragA But $2^{k_1}$ is not divisible by $2^{k_2}$ :) Just some minor adjustments.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I assume Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic in the proof.

Comment: To make the proof more idiomatic, you can say "without loss of generality $k_1 \gt k_2$"

Comment: Previously OP proved that if A,B is countable, then A×B is countable.

Comment: @LeAnhDung isn’t $2^5$ divisible by $2^2$?

Comment: @WilliamElliot This theorem is a lemma in that proof :)

Comment: @AnuragA I'm not sure what you meant. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Okay, then why don't you just say 'by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, it is injective'? Does the fundamental theorem of arithmetic not say that for a given prime factorization the factors and exponents are unique, and isn't your ordered pair the exponents of a prime factorization of the image point?

Comment: You can avoid having to define prime numbers and also fundamental theorem of arithmetic at the cost of defining rationals: $2^{k_1 - k_2} = 3^{l_2 - l_1}$. The left hand side is integer, so then the right hand side is as well ($l_2 \ge l_1$). But taking both sides mod 2, you obtain a contradiction unless $k_1 = k_2$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I should have mentioned that explicitly. Thanks!

Comment: @LeAnhDung It should have been the *only* thing you mentioned. All the rest is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a short proof based on @spaceisdarkgreen's comment:

Define $f(k,l)= 2^k3^l$. By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, $f$ is injective. QED.