# $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ is countably infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ is countable.

In this proof, I try to not use The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, so the proof may be needless long :)

---

**My attempt:**

We define $f:\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ by

$$f(i,j)=i+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{i+j}k$$

Next we prove that $f$ is injective.

For $(i_1,j_1),(i_2,j_2)\in \Bbb N\times\Bbb N$, $f(i_1,j_1)=f(i_2,j_2)\iff i_1+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{i_1+j_1}k = i_2+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{i_2+j_2}k$. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $i_1+j_1\le i_2+j_2$. Thus we have only two cases.

1. $i_1+j_1 = i_2+j_2$

Then $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{i_1+j_1}k = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{i_2+j_2}k$ and thus $i_1=i_2$. It also follows that $j_1=j_2$. Hence $(i_1,j_1)=(i_2,j_2)$.

2. $i_1+j_1 < i_2+j_2$

$i_1+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{i_1+j_1}k = i_2+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{i_2+j_2}k \iff \sum\limits_{k=0}^{i_2+j_2}k - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{i_1+j_1}k = i_1-i_2\iff \sum\limits_{k = i_1+j_1+1}^{i_2+j_2}k=i_1-i_2$.

$\sum\limits_{k = i_1+j_1+1}^{i_2+j_2}k \ge i_1+j_1+1 \iff i_1-i_2\ge i_1+j_1+1 \iff 0\ge -i_2\ge j_1+1$. This inequality is clearly a contradiction.

To sum up, we have only one possible cases in which $i_1+j_1 = i_2+j_2$.

Thus $f(i_1,j_1)=f(i_2,j_2)\iff (i_1,j_1)=(i_2,j_2)$. Hence $f$ is injective and $\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ is countable.

---

> Does this proof look fine or contain gaps? Do you have suggestions? Many thanks for your dedicated help!

Comment: Is for you $0\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Cornman Yes :)

Comment: My criticism, which is similar to suggestions I’ve given on a few of your many “check my proof” questions, is that your proofs seem to only try to be technically correct but not to actually communicate ideas. There is a very simple “picture” and intuition behind this construction, but I certainly wouldn’t know that from reading this proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can create a injective function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N^2.$ Construct a function $f:\Bbb N^2\rightarrow\Bbb N$. $f(x,y)=2^x3^y$ is also injective. Since we can create an injection both way, there exists a bijection.

Function2: Consider $a_1=\sum^n_{i=0}10^ik_1$ and $a_2=\sum^n_{i=0}10^ij_1$

Then $n=\overline{k_1j_1k_2j_2...}$

Comment: I tried to avoid The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic in this proof! I actually used exactly the same approach as yours at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2915138/bbb-n-times-bbb-n-is-countable ^^

Comment: @LeAnhDung this new function did not use the FTOA.

Comment: In fact it's bijective.

Comment: What is your purpose when you defined $a_1$ and $a_2$? I don't see where you used $a_1,a_2$.

Comment: @LeAnhDung $a_1,a_2$ are the x,y coordinate of $\Bbb R^2$

Comment: I do not understand what you are doing with your function 2. What is $k_1$? What is $j_1$? What is $k_2$ and $j_2$ and what is $n=\overline{k_1j_1k_2j_2\dotso}$ supposed to mean? A product? A series of didgets? A series of pereodic didgits?

Comment: $a_1$ and $a_2$ are two positive integers from $\Bbb N^2$. $n$ is the integer from $\Bbb N$. I created a bijection.